# AWS is out of sync with Israeli time - causing security errors

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clock, django-storage

When connecting with AWS service, [the connection time should be max 15 minutes for security reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770635/s3-error-the-difference-between-the-request-time-and-the-current-time-is-too-la)

This year in Israel, the winter clock change is postponed in about 2 months.

But amazon seems to not know about it, so if the correct israeli time is 14:00 PM, for amazon it is 13:00 PM.

This situation causes every request to the service to fail (S3 in particular)

---

1. Option 1 is that amazon fixes it, but it may take time.
2. Option 2 is to manually change the time on the server that makes the
   requests.

However, in my case, this is not possible because the server is a VM, and I don't have the privilege to change the time.

Is there another way to fix that? somehow to change the time on the server when connecting amazon service?

I'm using django with django-storages (boto) for connecting with S3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If S3 doesn't fix the issue and you don't want to adjust your server's time, you could compensate for the date difference by modifying the boto source code (see `HmacAuthV1Handler->add_auth`) or by [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) the original boto code.

Comment: how would you monkey patch the code to fix this issue? code will be great, but a guidance will also be appriciated

Comment: Just overwrite the `add_auth` method in the boto `HmacAuthV1Handler` class (the original code is in `auth.py`) and adjust the code `headers['Date'] = formatdate(usegmt=True)` to compensate for the time difference.

Answer (score 1):

Israel's time zone changes are accounted for in the 2013d version of the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  In Python, this is implemented via [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

According to [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/), Django *optionally* uses pytz.  You should therefore:

- Make sure you *are* using pytz in Django.
- Make sure you have the 2013d update to pytz.

You should also raise a support incident with Amazon if you haven't already.  They really should be staying on top of the IANA TZDB updates on their operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

@YardenST: AWS only needs to know that the request was signed by you with the right timezone conversion on your end. Your server's software needs to handle the timezone conversion to UTC correctly. If you can't fix your server's time, then [dcro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027148/dcro) has the right idea.

[Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) said:

> You should also raise a support incident with Amazon if you haven't already. They really should be staying on top of the IANA TZDB updates on their operating systems.

Yes, but [YardenST](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178000/yardenst) never said he was running Amazon Linux on EC2. If he were, then yes, that would be the thing to do. But then again, you have root access to EC2 servers, so that's still a userland problem to update your packages.

Comment: I'm not using EC2. while investigating the issue, i found out my server doesn't return the correct GMT time (date --utc), what probably causes the error, because this is the time boto uses when sending requests to amazon.