# AWS CLI S3 A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to setup a Amazon Linux AMI(ami-f0091d91) and have a script that runs a copy command to copy from a S3 bucket.

```bash
aws --debug s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/latest/codedeploy-agent.noarch.rpm .
```

This script works perfectly on my local machine but fails with the following error on the Amazon Image:

```bash
2016-03-22 01:07:47,110 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign: HEAD

Tue, 22 Mar 2016 01:07:47 GMT
x-amz-security-token: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
/aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/latest/codedeploy-agent.noarch.rpm
2016-03-22 01:07:47,111 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [HEAD]>
2016-03-22 01:07:47,111 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.amazonaws.com
2016-03-22 01:07:47,151 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "HEAD /latest/codedeploy-agent.noarch.rpm HTTP/1.1" 403 0
2016-03-22 01:07:47,151 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amz-id-2': '0mRvGge9ugu+KKyDmROm4jcTa1hAnA5Ax8vUlkKZXoJ//HVJAKxbpFHvOGaqiECa4sgon2F1kXw=', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-amz-request-id': '6204CD88E880E5DD', 'date': 'Tue, 22 Mar 2016 01:07:46 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/xml'}
2016-03-22 01:07:47,152 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:

2016-03-22 01:07:47,152 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.HeadObject: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f421075bcd0>
2016-03-22 01:07:47,152 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - No retry needed.
2016-03-22 01:07:47,152 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.HeadObject: calling handler <function enhance_error_msg at 0x7f4211085758>
2016-03-22 01:07:47,152 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.HeadObject: calling handler <awscli.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f421100cc90>
2016-03-22 01:07:47,152 - MainThread - awscli.errorhandler - DEBUG - HTTP Response Code: 403
2016-03-22 01:07:47,152 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.s3.s3handler - DEBUG - Exception caught during task execution: A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/s3handler.py", line 100, in call
    total_files, total_parts = self._enqueue_tasks(files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/s3handler.py", line 178, in _enqueue_tasks
    for filename in files:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/fileinfobuilder.py", line 31, in call
    for file_base in files:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 142, in call
    for src_path, extra_information in file_iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 314, in list_objects
    yield self._list_single_object(s3_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 343, in _list_single_object
    response = self._client.head_object(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 228, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 488, in _make_api_call
    model=operation_model, context=request_context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/errorhandler.py", line 70, in __call__
    http_status_code=http_response.status_code)
ClientError: A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
2016-03-22 01:07:47,153 - Thread-1 - awscli.customizations.s3.executor - DEBUG - Received print task: PrintTask(message='A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden', error=True, total_parts=None, warning=None)
A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

However, when I run it with the `--no-sign-request` option, it works perfectly:

```bash
aws --debug --no-sign-request s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2/latest/codedeploy-agent.noarch.rpm .
```

Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: It *looks like* you're (maybe implicitly) using the instance's IAM role to make the request (that would explain `x-amz-security-token` -- temporary credentials from the role) and your role denies access to S3... or the bucket (not yours, I take it?) doesn't allow access with credentials -- though if it's public, that's strange.  As always, make sure your system clock is correct, since with `HEAD` the error body is always suppressed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. The bucket that i'm trying access is, indeed, public. Not sure why it is complaining about a signed request then. It fails with similar error on my own bucket as well without the --no-sign-request option.

Comment: You do have an IAM role on this instance, right?  It sounds as if that role may be restricting things, perhaps in unexpected ways.

Comment: My answer for a similar situation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56743569/577652

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I figured it out. I had an error in my cloud formation template that was creating the EC2 instances. As a result, the EC2 instances that were trying to access the above code deploy buckets, were in different regions (not us-west-2). It seems like the access policies on the buckets (owned by Amazon) only allow access from the region they belong in. 
When I fixed the error in my template (it was wrong parameter map), the error disappeared

Comment: You wrote: "access policies on the buckets (owned by Amazon) only allow access from the region they belong in." Buckets don't "belong to a region". They are Global. Wish I understood what fixed your error.

Comment: Buckets actually are defined in a region.

Comment: Passing the bucket's region as parameter worked for me.

Comment: I was getting something similar on boto3 in a cross-region request, and discovered a bug in my policy in the process. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465600/5556676). Can't say it's the same fix here, but maybe that's a hint? @LeslieK

Comment: I have checked to know if `us-west-2a` would be different from `us-west-2b` and it turns out that it works either way. It does not contradict with your answer but it adds to it. Thanks.

Comment: @LeslieK AWS S3 bucket names are global, yes, but buckets themselves are always regional. To get the bucket region see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-location.html
Only in Google Cloud buckets can be multi-regional (but still confined to one multi-region like US or EU).

Comment: Basically what happens is if the API command does not specify the region, it will try to use the profile connected default so the bucket name will not be formed properly [see accessing bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro), as the URL includes the region.

Answer (score 81):

in my case the problem was the `Resource` statement in the user access policy.

First we had `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"`,
but in order to have access to objects within a bucket you need a `/*` at the end:
`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"`

From [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-permissions.html):

> Bucket access permissions specify which users are allowed access to the objects in a bucket and which types of access they have. Object access permissions specify which users are allowed access to the object and which types of access they have. For example, one user might have only read permission, while another might have read and write permissions.

Comment: Note that when you edit a policy, it can take a few minutes for the changes to be effective.

Answer (score 61):

Trying to solve this problem myself, I discovered that there is no HeadBucket permission.  It looks like there is, because that's what the error message tells you, but actually the `HEAD` operation requires the `ListBucket` permission.
I also discovered that my IAM policy and my bucket policy were conflicting.  Make sure you check both.

Comment: yes, this is the algorithm... https://youtu.be/YQsK4MtsELU?t=808 .  you need to make sure resource policy does not conflict with IAM policy

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - see also [this AWS support article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-listobjects-sync/).  For some reason, this permission is required for `aws s3 cp` of an object from a bucket.

Answer (score 20):

The minimal permissions that worked for me when running `HeadObject` on any object in `mybucket`:

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 20):

There could be a number of reason, (The most stupid one being)
AWS S3 throws **403 error** when the specified object or file **doesn't exist** at the location.

Comment: I disagree that this is "stupid." By using 403 for both not found and not authorized, they make it impossible to determine if a given object exists or not unless you have permission to list it.

Comment: I meant being stupid on my part, I used the wrong file name and spent almost a day trying to figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Would it not be better to return 403 no matter what if the user is unauthorized, but 404 if the user is authorized but the file does not exist?

Answer (score 17):

Check your object owner if you copy the file from another aws account.

In my case, I copy the file from another aws account without acl, so file's owner is the other aws account, it's mean the file belongs to origin account.

To fix it, copy or sync s3 files with acl, example:

```
aws s3 cp --acl bucket-owner-full-control s3://bucket1/key s3://bucket2/key
```

Comment: out of date because it has been replaced by `--acl` as per the help page ( accepts values of private,  public-read,  public-read-write,  authenticated-read, aws-exec-read, bucket-owner-read, bucket-owner-full-control and log-delivery-write). Thanks for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 9):

In my case, i got this error trying to get an object on an S3 bucket folder. But in that folder my object was not here (i put the wrong folder), so S3 send this message. Hope it could help you too.

Answer (score 7):

One of the reasons for this could be if you try accessing buckets of a region which requires V4-Signing. Try explicitly providing the region, as `--region cn-north-1`

Answer (score 7):

I've had this issue, adding `--recursive` to the command will help.

At this point it doesn't quite make sense as you (like me) are only trying to copy a single file down, but it does the trick!

Comment: It looked like success but the local downloaded "file" was in fact an empty directory

Comment: Yes, this suppresses the error, but the files are in fact NOT copied.

Answer (score 6):

403 - means I know who you are but you are not authorized to do what you asking.

In my case, the problem was in a Policy - I didn't choose an object when specified the Policy in Visual Editor

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Adding both `"arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name"` and `"arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name/*"` to policy congiguration fixed the issue for me.

Comment: this grants all S3 permissions. It is advisable to be restrictive and grant only the level of permissions required for the role, or user, or task for that matter.

Comment: `s3:*` is too wide permission set to be used practically

Answer (score 6):

**It's a terrible practice to give away access to the entire s3 (all actions, all buckets), just to unblock yourself.**

The 403 error above is usually due to the lack of "Read" permission of files.  The Read action for reading a file in S3 is `s3:GetObject`.

```json
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/path/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            ]
        }
```

### Solution 1: A new Policy in IAM (Tell Role/User to know S3)

You can create a Policy (e.g. `MY_S3_READER`) with the following, and attach it to the user or role that's doing the job. (e.g. EC2 Instance's IAM role)

Here is the exact JSON for your Policy: (just replace `mybucketname` and `path`)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/path/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Create this Policy.  Then, go to IAM > Roles > Attach Policy and attach it.

### Solution 2: Edit Buckey Policy in S3 (Tell S3 to know User/Role)

Go to your bucket in S3, then add the following example: (replace `mybucketname` and `myip`)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "SourceIP",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ValidIpAllowRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "myip/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to change this read permission to by User or Role (instead of IP Address), remove the `Condition` part, and change "Principal" to `"Principal": { "AWS": "<IAM User/Role's ARN>" },`".

### Additional Notes

1. Check the permissions via `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 ls` manually for faster debugging.
2. It sometimes takes up to 30 seconds for the permission change to be effective.  Be patient.
3. Note that for doing "`ls`" (e.g. `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mypath`) you need `s3:ListBucket` access.
4. **IMPORTANT** Accessing files by their HTTP(S) URL via `cURL` or similar tools (e.g. `axios` on AJAX calls) requires you to grant either IP access, or supply proper headers, manually, or [get a signedUrl from the SDK](https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530) first.

Comment: Doesn't having only a GetObject permission on the bucket not allow you to write to the bucket? What's the point of only being able to read from something you can't write to?

Comment: @AlxVallejo, there are tons of use cases for that. e.g., you might want to limit which microservice can write User Photos to S3 to only one service, while some other services can have read-only access to read those photos and show them to other users, or generate SEO landing pages.

Comment: That's business logic though. Having business logic in an s3 configuration is bad practice imo. s3 clients should have all capabilities and access to that client should be limited accordingly.

Comment: I'd call that an extra layer of security. :)

Comment: Extra security that causes headaches because the business logic is now duplicated across systems. Oh look, HR wants to see you now.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply use the following AWS IAM policy keeping in mind the AWS best practices and principle of least privilege:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Sid1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET_NAME]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Sid2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET_NAME]/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the error `A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden` for my aws cli copy command `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file file`. I was using a IAM role which had full S3 access using an `Inline Policy`.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I give it the full S3 access from  the `Managed Policies` instead, then the command works. I think this must be a bug from Amazon, because the policies in both cases were exactly the same.

Comment: Btw, I was trying to use [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys/) to mount an s3 bucket in my ubuntu server filesystem via an IAM user attached to a similar policy to the above but with `Resource: "example"` set (instead of `*`), and that caused the inability to create files there ([similar issue](https://github.com/kahing/goofys/issues/165)). I just changed it to the `managed policy` of `AmazonS3FullAccess`

Comment: This is a bad answer - you should never allow policies that allow access to everything

Comment: It's a workaround as long as the original bug is not fixed

Comment: I can't believe I landed on my own post 3 years later again :/

Comment: It only allows access to all S3 buckets that the account has, and may be denied by bucket policies anyhow. However you should always deny public access to buckets unless you really know what you are doing ! ;-D

Comment: @Shadi Hopefully in 3 years you learned not to enable full access to s3 :)

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error message due to my EC2 instance's clock being out of sync.

I was able to fix on Ubuntu using this:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Comment: Odd enough, but this fixed my issue too.

Comment: You can keep it sync'd to Amazon's servers directly https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667543/1109316

Answer (score 3):

If running in an environment where the credential/role is not clear, be sure you included the `--profile=yourprofile` flag so the cli knows what credentials to use. For example:

`aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket destination.txt --profile=yourprofile`

will succeed while the following yielded the HeadObject error

`aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket destination.txt`

The profile settings reference entries in your `config` and `credentials` files.

Answer (score 3):

I had a lambda function doing the same, copy from bucket to bucket.

The lambda had permissions to use the source bucket as trigger.

**Configuration tab**

[image]

But it also needs permissions to OPERATE with buckets.

**Permissions tab**

[image]

If s3 is not there, then you need to edit the **Role** used by the lambda and add it (see the s3FullAccess)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:HeadObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Assign this policy to an IAM role which is assigned to your ec2 (or any service thats trying to access your S3)

Comment: I've already assigned AmazonS3FullAccess to the user I am using to communicate with AWS but I still get this `error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Forbidden` when I try to do this: `aws s3api head-bucket --bucket "asda"`. Have any idea?

Comment: The action s3:HeadObject does not exist. Did you mean s3:GetObject? The API called HeadObject authorizes against the IAM action s3:GetObject.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error with a mis-configured test event. I changed the source buckets ARN but forgot to edit the default S3 bucket name.

I.e. make sure that in the bucket section of the test event both the ARN and bucket name are set correctly:

```
"bucket": {
  "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name",
  "name": "your_bucket_name",
  "ownerIdentity": {
    "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a 403 on HEAD requests while the GET requests were working. It turned out to be the CORS config in s3 permissions. I had to add HEAD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced that behaviour. In my case I've found that if the IAM policy doesn't have access to read the object (`s3:GetObject`), the same error is raised.

I agree with you that the error raised from aws console & cli is not really well explained and may cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to cross-account S3 access

An IAM user policy will not over-ride the policy defined for the bucket in the foreign account.

s3:GetObject must be allowed for accountA/user as well as on the accountB/bucket

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was because I had enabled MFA, and given it the access key and the secret key, but not allowed token authentication in the docker image I was using.  This can also cause this error.  It is a very broadly applicable error.

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this scenario.

I have a bucket with policy that uses AWS4-HMAC-SHA256. Turns out my awscli is not updated to the latest version. Mine was aws-cli/1.10.8. Upgrading it have solved the problem.

`pip install awscli --upgrade --user`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

Answer (score 1):

I got this fixed by setting the system time correctly.

Ensure the aws bucket region is right and your system time matches the aws region time

Answer (score 1):

When I faced this issue, I discovered that my problem was that the files in the 'Source Account' were copied there by a 'third party' and the Owner was not the Source Account.

I had to recopy the objects to themselves in the same bucket with the --metadata-directive REPLACE

Detailed explanation in [Amazon Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-cross-account-access-denied/)

Answer (score 1):

> **Permissions**
>
> You need the s3:GetObject permission for this operation. For more
> information, see Specifying Permissions in a Policy. If the object you
> request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether
> you also have the s3:ListBucket permission.
>
> ```
> If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 returns an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
>
> If you don’t have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 returns an HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.
> ```
>
> The following operation is related to HeadObject:
>
> ```
> GetObject
> ```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone.  In my case, I was running a CodeBuild job and the CodeBuild execution role had full access to S3.  I was trying to list keys in an S3 bucket via the CLI.  However, I was using the CLI from within the `aws-cli` Docker image and passing the credentials via environment variables per this article:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-versions

No matter what I tried, any calls using `aws s3api ...` would fail with that same 403 error.  The solution for me was to convert to a normal s3 CLI call (as opposed to s3api CLI call):

`aws s3 ls s3://bucket/key --recursive`

This change worked.  The call using `aws s3api did not`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your Police permission gived for the role that you are using,
In Case you are using AWS Glue you need create police with these permissions,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-sagemaker-notebook-policy.html

This will solve `"(403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was 99% sure that it was due to lack of permissions so I changed the policy of IAM role to full access even though it is not good practice. Using:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

as stated in above comments from others.

However, this did not work because I had just created my AWS account on Sunday evening and I wanted to use it immediately.
I was in a US East region which was 12 hours behind my time. It took all night to me to try to solve the issue without success.

I came back on Tuesday afternoon on the same Notebook and everything worked like charm.

It is not true that the change of permission takes a few minutes.
It can take up to 48h.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we were trying to set up cross-account access to a different company's bucket, and oddly enough listing the bucket contents worked (`ls` in the CLI), but getting any objects (`cp`) returned this error.

It turned out that the problem was that even though both the policy for the other company's bucket and the IAM policy for our user were configured correctly, their bucket also had *ACL* enabled. The ACL was left at the default, i.e. granting access only to the bucket owner.

I'm not clear on why this even allows listing bucket contents (would think that if ACL overrides the policy, that would apply to all actions), but anyway once Object Ownership was set back to the default `Bucket owner enforced` - disabling the ACL altogether - everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

**if someone ends up here and is trying to implement solution in terraform, this is mine:**

```
module "s3_files_label" {
  source      = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-null-label.git?ref=0.24.1"
  namespace   = var.client
  environment = var.environment
  attributes  = ["backend-api-logs"]
}

module "s3_files" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "2.7.0"

  bucket = module.s3_files_label.id
  acl    = "private"

  cors_rule = jsonencode([
    {
      allowed_headers = ["*"]
      allowed_methods = ["GET", "PUT", "POST"]
      allowed_origins = ["https://${var.route53_domain}"]
      expose_headers  = []
      max_age_seconds = 0
    }
  ])
}

module "s3_user" {
  source      = "cloudposse/iam-system-user/aws"
  version     = "0.20.2"
  namespace   = var.client
  environment = var.environment
  name        = "s3-user"

  inline_policies_map = {
    s3 = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:HeadObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "${module.s3_files.s3_bucket_arn}",
                "${module.s3_files.s3_bucket_arn}/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "list",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
  }

  tags = module.config.tags
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but the solution was different than all above - I was trying to hit it via transfer accelerated endpoint, but it wasnt enabled on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, the error can also be caused by missing permissions on the KMS key used for the SSE-KMS of the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on wsl, there are chances your system clock is skewed.

Try running  `wsl -d docker-desktop -e /sbin/hwclock -s` from PowerShell, after making sure docker-desktop is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had set a CDN subdomain, and so needed to set `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = "mysub.domain.com"`.