# A client error (400) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to copy a file from a private s3-bucket via cli to my ec2 instance. The ec2 is in the same region as the bucket and has the following IAM role attached (AmazonS3FullAccess):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": "s3:*",
     "Resource": "*"
   }
 ]
}
```

But the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://[BUCKETNAME]/index.html /var/www/html/
```

fails with the error:

> A client error (400) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining.

I already double checked the spelling of the bucket name...

Comment: Is that the full cp command line you were running?  cp also needs an argument for the local path name.

Comment: sorry i forgot this part in the posting, but it was there:
' aws s3 cp s3://[bucketname]/index.html /var/www/html/ '

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I added the --region option to the statement and everything is working now:

```
aws s3 cp s3:/[BUCKETNAME]/ . --recursive --region [REGION]
```

Comment: you can add the Default region when running `aws configure`

Answer (score 43):

This error also happens when your session has expired if using temporary security credentials with an assumed role. Not a forbidden or unknown id as you would expect.

Answer (score 9):

The `--region` parameter did not work for me.

I tried using `--profile`, and it worked all fine.

```
aws s3api head-bucket --bucket xxxx --profile dev-profile
```

Answer (score 5):

My problem got fixed as soon as I upgraded to the latest version of aws cli. Here is how you upgrade :
`pip install --upgrade --user awscli`

specifying the region wasn't helpful

Answer (score 0):

When I changed my same policy from "inline policies" to "managed policies" it worked. Ref my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37532132/4126114

Comment: My bad. I meant "inline" to "managed". Will edit. Blame it on programming late at night

Comment: What's your output for `aws --version`? Mine is `aws-cli/1.10.16 Python/2.7.3 Linux/3.13.0-86-generic botocore/1.4.7`

Comment: Mine is: aws-cli/1.10.8 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.3.30

Comment: if i run the cp command with the option --region it works. Strange because the bucket as well as the ec2 instance remain to the same region. 

I'm confused...

Comment: Looks like your awscli configuration is missing the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` parameter. Check [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli#accessing-services-with-global-endpoints). You can try using `aws configure` as described [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli#getting-started) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli#examples). Otherwise you can just upgrade your awscli with `pip install --upgrade awscli` to the most recent version.

Comment: i added the option --region in the user data script so everything is just working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had `use_accelerate_endpoint` set to true in my AWS config file (`~/.aws/config`). Changing it to false fixed the issue. This is what my config file looks like now:

```
[default]
region = us-west-2
output = json
s3 =
    use_accelerate_endpoint = false
```