# Getting fatal error while using aws CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy my app via aws' CodeDeploy. I am following this example https://github.com/abel30567/AWS_CodeDeploy_Example

But when I run command `aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region us-east-1`

I get an error saying `fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

I don't know what is wrong. I followed all the steps correctly. Is it any issue with Users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144757/aws-cli-s3-a-client-error-403-occurred-when-calling-the-headobject-operation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS CLI S3 A client error (403) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144757/aws-cli-s3-a-client-error-403-occurred-when-calling-the-headobject-operation)