# How do I solve the AWS error: "The difference between the request time and the current time is too large" front-end only?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend

I currently have an app that allows uploads to AWS S3, the upload is handled purely from the front-end of the app in js with the `aws-sdk`. We had some users facing this issue mentioned in the title (`The difference between the request time and the current time is too large`) which prevents them from uploading properly.

I am aware of the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770635/s3-error-the-difference-between-the-request-time-and-the-current-time-is-too-la), but I was wondering if there was anything I could do to make sure this doesn't happen again for any of the users, with front-end changes only. Is there a way I can make my request be in sync properly ?

I tried having some users sync their clock, but it either did not work or they didn't do it properly. Unfortunately I cannot rely on the user to fix this.

Comment: You could have your app collect their local time and check it against a server before allowing an upload, alerting the user if the check fails, and disabling the "upload" functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/399#issuecomment-233057244

Try this:

```
AWS.events.on('retry', function(response) {  
      if (response.error.name === 'RequestTimeTooSkewed') {
        console.error('User time is not correct. Handling error!');
        console.log('AWS systemClockOffset:', AWS.config.systemClockOffset);
        var serverTime = Date.parse(response.httpResponse.headers['date']);
        var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('AWS timestamp:', new Date(serverTime));
        console.log('Browser timestamp:', new Date(timeNow));
        AWS.config.systemClockOffset = Math.abs(timeNow - serverTime);
        response.error.retryable = true;
        console.log('Setting systemClockOffset to:', AWS.config.systemClockOffset);
        console.log('Retrying uploading to S3 once more...');
      }
});
```

You detect how much the clock is off by, set AWS.config.systemClockOffset to the difference, and retry

Comment: In addition to this, one needs to add `<ExposeHeader>Date</ExposeHeader>` into the CORS config of the bucket to allow exposing the date field. Thanks for the help!

Comment: if i use Aws SDK 2.7.27 written in PHP, where do i insert the code above? is it inside the SDK or inside the AWS console? where?

Comment: It's not inside the SDK, this code is used on the client consuming the SDK.

Comment: events property is not available in aws-sdk anymore - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#systemClockOffset-property

Answer (score 8):

I faced similar issue with **S3** upload and on **Cognito**. Try adding **correctClockSkew: true** in the config block where you set accessKeyId and secretAccessKey. Like below:

> ```
> AWS.config.update({
> accessKeyId: awsCredentials.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
> secretAccessKey: awsCredentials.SECRET_KEY_ID,
> correctClockSkew: true,  
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me using the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/43642178/1141612 and your solution.

Comment: Does this require exposing the Date header too?

Comment: This worked wonders for us too.  Our use case was downloading many (4k) 50MB(ish) files from S3.  We kept seeing OP's error around the 15-16 minute mark.  I wish AWS defaulted this to true!!!!!!!!!!